# Slide transitions in Windows Universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

I am working on porting a Windows Phone Silverlight app to Windows 10 Universal.  One thing that I did with my previous silverlight app I used the Windows Phone Toolkit to provide me with Transitions that I could run in code:

```
var slideTransition = new SlideTransition() { Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideRightFadeIn };
ITransition transition = slideTransition.GetTransition(ctrl);
transition.Completed += delegate
{
    transition.Stop();
};
transition.Begin();
```

However, I can seem to find anything similar for Win10 Universal.  I saw that there is a SlideNavigationTransitionInfo class, but I haven't seen any examples of how to use it in code, and it doesn't seem to have the same capabilities as the slideTransition.

Answer (score 1):

There is the samples [Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples), maybe it can help you.

There also have win8.1 animation sample [XAML personality animations sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Personality-Animations-3f857919), it is similar to windows 10.

Comment: I ended up just downloading the source code for WinPhone Toolkit (https://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), pulled out the Transitions related files, and then recompiled for Windows Universal.  Most of the issues compiling are related to the different namespaces.

Comment: The universal samples is actually pretty good. Look at the XamlUIBasics project to see the possibilities. Pivot might be what you need.